# Invoke-RestMethod -Method Delete Base Request

Tags: powershell

I'm at a loss. I can run the following and it works flawlessly

```
Invoke-RestMethod 'https://deerlakes.freshservice.com/api/v2/vendors/13000042524' -Headers $FDHeaders -Method Get
```

But as soon as I run

```
Invoke-RestMethod 'https://deerlakes.freshservice.com/api/v2/vendors/13000042524' -Headers $FDHeaders -Method Delete
```

I get a bad request

> Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>   At line:19 char:1
>   + Invoke-RestMethod 'https://deerlakes.freshservice.com/api/v2/vendors/ ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: 400 normally means the request is expecting something different to what you are passing. This could be in the form of the url looking different, or some missing/extranious variables - you might need to check the api reference for how to properly call delete on that endpoint

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that their was a contract associated with the vendor in Freshservice that wouldn't allow me to delete the vendor.